# Como receber o retorno de uma Procedure usando ODBC no PHP?

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, odbc

Estou tentando comunicar o PHP com o banco de dados Caché da Intersystems, porém precisarei usar ODBC para comunicar.

Minha dúvida é como consigo pegar no PHP o retorno da Procedure, no caso uma String, já estou conseguindo executar com sucesso, mas o retorno não sei como pegar. Estou usando as funções `odbc_prepare` e `odbc_execute`.

Minha conexão com o Banco de Dados

```
$usu='usuario';
$senha='senha1234';
$connection_string = 'Driver={InterSystems ODBC35};server=localhost;port=1972;database=MEUBD;protocol=TCP;static cursors=1';
$connection = odbc_connect($connection_string,$usu,$senha);
```

Execução da minha Procedure

```
<?php
$sqlExecutar = '{CALL %MeuModulo.MinhaClasse_MinhaProcedure(?,?,?)}';
$exc = odbc_prepare($connection, $sqlExecutar);
$par1='Parametro 1';
$par2='Parametro 2';
$par3='Parametro 3';
$result = odbc_execute($exc,array($par1,$par2,$par3));
?>
```

`$result` volta com o valor `True`

Como consigo receber o retorno da Procedure? No caso ela está retornando a palavra `"SUCESSO NA EXECUÇÃO"`. Existe algum método `odbc`?

Agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O retorno é `true` pois está retornando que a [função foi executada com sucesso](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.odbc-execute.php).

Poderia usar o `odbc_fetch_array`:

```
$rs = odbc_execute($exc,array($par1,$par2,$par3));

if (is_resource($rs)) {
    while ($result[] = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) {
    }
    odbc_free_result($rs);
    $this->close();
    return $result;
} else {
    $this->halt('Database query error', $sql);
}
```

Fontes: [Link 1](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/odbc_fetch_array/php-odbc_fetch_array-function-examples.html), [Link 2](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.odbc-fetch-array.php)